# What does subtraction on linear tranforms mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, linear-transformations

Here's the background:

I'm currently reading through Sheldon Axlers *Linear algebra done right*, and I'm currently working with eigenvalues to linear tranforms. Yet, It might've just been me who missed it the first time but, the concept of $$T - \lambda I$$ keeps showing up, but I can't seem to find what that actually represent, the first instance of the notation I've found is
the equation $$Tu = \lambda u \Leftrightarrow (T-\lambda I)u = 0$$
      *so λ is an eigenvalue of T if and only if T − λI is not injective*

Which leads me to believe, that since we're having two equivalent tranforms, they "cancel each other" and we're left with a zero transform, i.e. a transform that always takes its elements to 0.

But as you can see, this isn't especially rigorous, so my question:

**What does the operation "subtraction" represent in the context of linear tranforms?**

Any context of what this means in combination with null() and range() would also be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the eigenvector-eigenvalue relation you've shown, $\lambda$ is a scalar quantity while $I$ is the identity matrix. Thus, the term

$$(T - \lambda I)$$

corresponds to subtracting $\lambda$ from the diagonal elements of the linear operator $T$

Answer (score 0):

Subtraction of linear transformations is just like subtraction of functions. If $T_1, T_2:V \to W$ are linear transformations then $T_1 - T_2$ is another linear transformation from $V \to W$ defined by:

$$
(T_1 - T_2)(v) := T_1(v) - T_2(v)
$$

for all $v \in V$. Note that $(T - \lambda I)u = 0$ does not mean that $T - \lambda I$ is the zero transformation. It just means that $u \in \ker(T - \lambda I)$. If the equation $(T - \lambda I)u = 0$ is to hold for any nonzero vectors $u$, then this means that $\ker(T - \lambda I) \neq \{0\}$. This in turn tells you that $T - \lambda I$ is not injective.